# why is my datasource not found in Lucee?

Tags: datasource, lucee

I installed the latest build of Lucee (4.5) on my windows 2012 server. I configured it with a datasource. The datasource verifies as OK. In my code I am simply trying to connect to it using:

```
<cfquery name=q1 datasource=test>
  select * from table1
</cfquery>
```

but I am getting an error saying that the datasource does not exist and the available datasource names are []

The database I'm using is MySQL.

Why can it not see my datasource?

Comment: Did you add the data source to your server admin or a web admin?  If web, check and make sure you didn't add it to another context.  The server admin URL is /lucee/admin/server.cfm and the web admin is /lucee/admin/web.cfm

Comment: To add to what Brad said, you could try adding the datasource to the server admin, which will work across all web contexts, and see if it works.

Comment: That was my problem. I only added it to the Web side of the admin. I'm coming from Adobe's ColdFusion and I'm not used to this config yet. What is the purpose of having a web admin and a server admin?

Comment: My comment was too long...  I guess I'll just turn it into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike Adobe CF, each Lucee site runs in its own context.  This is designed for separation and control of settings-- especially helpful for shared hosting.

There are three tiers of settings in Lucee Server.  Precedence is given from the bottom up.

1. The Server admin applies to the entire server.
2. The Web admin can override or augment the server settings and it only applies to that web context (unique URL if you're using mod_cfml).
3. A specific app's settings can be overridden by settings in the Application.cfc.

There is nothing wrong with putting your data source in the web admin, but you apparently put it in the wrong one.  I'm guessing you were on the default context associated with localhost.  The hostname in the URL controls the web context that you are editing.  i.e.

localhost/lucee/admin/web.cfm
anotherHostName.com/lucee/admin/web.cfm

If you want to see a list of all the web contexts, log into the server admin and scroll to the bottom of the home page.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I haven't found much useful documentation on Lucee yet.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
<cfquery name="q1" datasource="test">
 select * from table1
</cfquery>
```

Strange error. Should that be fine Adam?